# having java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error come up, as well as j not seeming like a variable in print statement, when is declared in loop

Tags: java

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DriversLicense {

    public static void main(String[]args){
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int count = 0;
        int wrong = 0;
        String pass;
        int j;
        
        String[] arr = {"B", "D", "A", "A", "C", "A", "B", "A", "C", "D", "B", "C", "D", "A", "D", "C", "C", "B", "D", "A"};
        String[] answers = new String [arr.length];
        int[] w = new int[arr.length];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter your answer:");
            answers[i] = input.next();
            if(answers[i].equals(arr[i])) {
                count++;
            }
            else {
                wrong++; 
                w[i] = i;
            }
        }
        int[] y = TestDriversLicense.numWrong(arr, answers, w, wrong);
        if((TestDriversLicense.Pass(count))){
            pass = "Pass!";
        }
        else {
            pass = "Fail!";
        }
        System.out.println(pass);
        System.out.println("You got "+ TestDriversLicense.Total(count)+ " correct!");
        System.out.println("You got "+ TestDriversLicense.Inc(wrong)+ " wrong!");
        if(wrong == 0) {
        }
        else {
            for(j = 0; j < y.length; j++);
            System.out.println("Your wrong answers were number(s) #"+ y[j]);
//attempting to print out the numbers for the wrong answers
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

attempting to print out the numbers of the questions answered incorrectly

```java
public class TestDriversLicense {

    public static boolean Pass(int n) {
        int pass = n;
        if(pass >= 15) {
        return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public static int Total(int correct) {
        int c = correct;
        return c;
    }
    public static int Inc(int n) {
        int inc = n;
        return inc;
    }
    public static int[] numWrong(String[] a, String[] ans, int[] b, int t) {
        int[] x = new int[t];
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        }
        x =b;
        return x;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: a lot of it is very messy, that is because i have been trying to fix the issue in different ways for the last hour. any help is appreciated, including other ways on how to get all the wrong question numbers in a seperate method.